# Class Member Instantiation

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class ClassA
{
    private SomeOtherClass _someOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass();     
}
```

or

```
public class ClassB
{
    private SomeOtherClass _someOtherClass;

    public ClassB()
    {
         _someOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass();
    }
}
```

or

```
public ClassC
{
    SomeOtherClass _someOtherClass
    public SomeOtherClass someOtherClass
    {
        get{
            if(_someOtherClass == null)
            {
                _someOtherClass = new SomeOtherClass();
            }
            return _someOtherClass;
        }
    }
}
```

All of the above accomplish populating a property with an instance of an object. Is there a benefit to one of them over the other ones?  In practice, I only use C when I don't have control over the construction of a class (like in a GUI). A smells a bit to me, but I don't have a concrete reason for that smell.

Note I am omitting the Inversion Of Control (IOC) pattern from the discussion as the benefits of that are well known and I of course use it often.  This question is more about the case of a simple class that may not need that pattern.

Comment: Neither A nor B involve a property.

Comment: I am not sure I get the sense of your question clearly... Once I had discovered a lot of thing about this when I was playing with deserialization of objects, when deserializing, Constructor is never call if I recall well.  So C would be a better approach for deserialization...

Comment: In C# 6 you will be able to do `public SomeClass MyProperty {get;} = new SomeClass();`

Answer (score 3):

A and B are almost the same (implementation details on the order, but not important in this case).

I would use C when:

- The initialization of the variable can be delayed, or isn't frequently used;
- I want to optimize the initialization time and memory of the class.

Another option for C is the use of [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx), but that is out of scope for the question I think.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first and second example works the same, but I can say that the second one is much cleaner than the first one, because the instantiation is in the constructor, and the purpose of the constructor is usually to initialize the object's members that can be defined at that moment. In this way, you can easily know what has been instantiated just by looking at the constructor, and not searching through all the fields. In any of the first two cases, you could mark the field as `readonly` if you don't change it's value after that.

I see the third one as a kind of lazy loading, because you will initialize the field when you get the property. I use this when I am not sure if I will use the object within the class, so it is created per request. However, it has the minimal overhead of checking everytime if the field is instantiated, but it's nothing to worry about with current hardware. If you will use the object only within the class, you can mark the property as `private`, because it has no reason to be seen from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

A and B are (as said in other answers) basically the same. The property is populated when the class is constructed.

C doesn't populate the property on construction of the class, but only when it's accessed, which can be useful for a number of reasons (for example performance). Furthermore, it also has the side-effect that the property will never be able to be 'null' (whenever it's accessed, which could be an advantage or a disadvantage, depending on what the property is used for.